# Как в node.js создать xml-разметку?

Tags: javascript, node.js

В цикле создаю xml разметку. Нужное количество элементов 'rect' создать получается. А вот как создать xml дерево?

К примеру создать один тег 'grup' в него запихнуть тег 'class' и уже туда кучу тегов  в цикле?

Должно получиться так:

```
<grup param="silver">
  <class all="add">
     <rect> </rect>
     <rect> </rect>
     <rect> </rect>
     <rect> </rect>
     <rect> </rect>
  </class> 
</grup>
```

Делал так:

```
var i;
var tegs;
var grup;
var Class;
for (i = 0; i < sum_rect; i++) {

  tegs = '<rect ' + 'x' + '=' + '"' + nev_massiv[i] + '"' + 'y' + '=' + '"' + nev_massiv_y[i] + '"' + '> ' +
    '</rect>';
  Class = '<class>' + tegs + '<class>'
  grup = '<grup>' + Class + 'grup'

  fs.appendFile('index.html', grup, function(err) {
    if (err)
      throw err;
  })
}
```

Но результат получается такой:

```
<grup>
  <class> 
     <rect> 
     </rect>
   </class>
</grup>
```

А нужно чтобы теги 'grup', 'class' создались только один раз, а все остальные теги 'rect' добавлялись внутрь этих тегов

Comment: Так если `grup` и `class` должны создаваться **один** раз, зачем вы их положили внутрь цикла?

Comment: @D-side, я об этом знаю, но если даже убрать , то тогда все теги начнет создавать рядом. Нужно знать как  положить внутрь тех тегом другие теги.

Comment: Тут много способов есть. Можно опереться на то, что `appendFile` можно вызвать несколько раз: можно отдельно теги открыть и закрыть. А можно модифицировать цикл так, чтобы он `tegs` не **пере**записывал, а **до**писывал. Вы понимаете, что делает написанный вами код сейчас?

Comment: @ D-side 4 , четного говоря с трудом. Но к примеру если я вызвать appendFile 2 раза,  то каким образом дочерние теги положить в материнские? У меня получаться только добавить теги возле материнских но не внутрь... А как можно модифицировать цикл ?

Comment: Сейчас у вас результат цикла накапливается только в `i`, потому что она инициализируется в начале (`i = 0`), и меняется на каждом шаге (`i++`). Примерно так же можно поступить и с `tegs`. И пока я ещё здесь, рекомендую заняться переименованием: tegs > tags, grup > group, massiv > array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно немного структурировать код.

1. Выделить общую функцию которая будет генерировать разметку для конкретного тега, по переданным параметрам, например

   ```
   function Tag(tagName, attrs, inner) {
     return `<${tagName}${attrs&&(' '+attrs)}>${inner||''}</${tagName}>`;
   }
   ```

   Тут просто берутся параметры: имя тега, строка с атрибутами, и строка внутреннего содержания и компонуются в конечную строку.
2. Так же можно выделить отдельную функцию которая будет по конкретному объекту собирать строку с атрибутами, например

   ```
   function Attrs(attrs) {
     return Object.keys(attrs).map(function(key) {// бежим по свойствам объекта
       return `${key}="${attrs[key]}"`;//формируем строку 'key="value"'
     }).join(' ');// объединяем все в одну строку
   }
   ```
3. Далее можно конкретизировать нужные теги, в данном случае `Group`, `Class`, `Rect` - создав их на основе общей функции

   ```
   var Group = Tag.bind(null, 'group'),
     Class = Tag.bind(null, 'class'),
     Rect = Tag.bind(null, 'rect');
   ```

   Теперь есть три функции в которых установлены значения для параметра `tagName`
4. Далее в цикле нужно просто собрать массив из результатов функции `Rect`

   ```
   var rects = [];

   for (i = 0; i < sum_rect; i++) {
     rects.push(Rect(Attrs({ // задаем необходимые атрибуты
       x: nev_massiv[i],
       y: nev_massiv_y[i]
     })));
   }
   ```
5. И теперь собираем все вместе:

   ```
   var result = Group(Attrs({}), Class(Attrs({}), rects.join('')));
   ```

   В переменной `result` лежит необходимая разметка.

Пример в сборе:

```js
var nev_massiv = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  nev_massiv_y = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
  sum_rect = 5;

function Attrs(attrs) {
  return Object.keys(attrs).map(function(key) {
    return `${key}="${attrs[key]}"`;
  }).join(' ');
}

function Tag(tagName, attrs, inner) {
  return `<${tagName}${attrs&&(' '+attrs)}>${inner||''}</${tagName}>`;
}
var Group = Tag.bind(null, 'group'),
  Class = Tag.bind(null, 'class'),
  Rect = Tag.bind(null, 'rect');

var rects = [];

for (i = 0; i < sum_rect; i++) {
  rects.push(Rect(Attrs({
    x: nev_massiv[i],
    y: nev_massiv_y[i]
  })));
}

var result = Group(Attrs({}), Class(Attrs({}), rects.join('')));

document.getElementById('r').textContent = result.replace(/(<((\/)?(.+?\b)).*?>)/g,function($0,$1,$2){ var tabs = {rect: '\n        ','/rect':'', 'class': '\n    ','/class':'\n    ','group':'', '/group':'\n'}; return tabs[$2]+$0;});;
```

```html
<pre id='r'></pre>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое то, что нужно

Answer (score 2):

просто используй [libxmljs](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs/wiki)

```
var doc = new libxml.Document();
doc
.node('root')
    .node('child').attr({foo: 'bar'})
        .node('grandchild', 'grandchild content').attr({baz: 'fizbuzz'})
    .parent()
.parent()
.node('sibling', 'with content!');
```

даст

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <child foo="bar">
        <grandchild baz="fizbuzz">grandchild content</grandchild>
    </child>
    <sibling>with content!</sibling>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот как я решил:

```js
var massiv_tegs = []; // масив содержащий нужную разметку
var i; //-- переменна щетчика

//-- формирование разметки
for (i = 0; i < sum_rect; i++) {
  tegs = '<rect ' + 'x' + '=' + '"' + nev_massiv[i] + '"' + 'y' + '=' + '"' + nev_massiv_y[i] + '"' + '> ' +
    '</rect>';
  massiv_tegs.push(tegs);
}
// добавление элементов
massiv_tegs.unshift('<svg>');
massiv_tegs.push('<svg>')

//-- вывод разметки в файл
massiv_tegs.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
  fs.appendFile('index.html', item, function(err) {
    if (err)
      throw err;
  })
});
```

Comment: если использовать у массива метод `join`, то не нужен цикл `forEach`: `fs.appendFile('index.html', massiv_tegs.join(''), function(err) {...}`

Comment: Не знал  спасибо